# Bitbucket Pipeline to modify files when merging to master

Tags: continuous-integration, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

I am new to bitbucket and CI/CD process in general so excuse me if the question seems very basic. I have a bitbucket repository which contains LookML files (https://docs.looker.com/data-modeling/learning-lookml/what-is-lookml)

Some of these files contain a 'connection: abc_staging' as the first line in the file.
I need to configure a bitbucket pipeline that replaces 'abc_staging' to 'abc_production' when a user merges code into the master branch. 
And the opposite when the user syncs his development branch with master.

This is how one of the target files look like -

connection: "abc_staging"

label: "Google Analytics Data"

include: "*.view"

include: "*.dashboard"
...